# sass — how to convert parent- to id-selector

Tags: sass

I have this:

```
.a-btn {
   //rules here
   ##{&}__label {
     //more rules
   }
 }
```

so I am after such an output:

```
.a-btn {…}
#a-btn__label {…}
```

**BUT** That compiles to this error:

```
 SassError: Invalid CSS after "#": expected selector, was "#.a-btn"
```

So I need to convert `.a.btn` to `a-btn`. Therefore I have tried to use `str-slice` like that:

```
.a-btn {
   //rules here
   ##{str-slice(&, 2)}__label {
     //more rules
   }
 }
```

But that yields:

```
SassError: argument `$string` of `str-slice($string, $start-at, $end-at:-1)` must be a string
```

Comment: Have you tried `##{str-slice(#{&}, 2)}__label`?

Comment: Nope, but that's it!!!

Comment: Yeah, nice! I was not sure (^_^;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
.a-btn 
  @at-root ##{str-slice(#{&},2)}__label
    height: 200px
    width: 200px
    background: red
```